# Sending Text message to AT&T network iPhone from Shell Script

Tags: iphone, bash, shell, sms-gateway

I am able to send text to the mobile which has Verizon network using simple SMS gateway as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash
mail 1234567890@vtext.com < sample.txt
```

Above Code sends the data of sample.text to phone number - 1234567890
But SMS gateway is not working for mobile with AT&T network. For example, following code does not work.

```
#!/bin/bash
mail 9876543210@txt.att.net < sample.txt
```

I have gone through the following link as well but for AT&T networked phone, its not working. 
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/203751/is-there-any-way-to-send-sms-to-a-mobile-number-using-shell-script

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Update:
sample.txt is just a text file with let's say just 1 line
Hello World

Also the server is same. From this server, I am able to send text to Verizon networked phone but NOT to the AT&T networked phone.

Comment: Most of the major carriers have very restrictive spam filtering in place to prevent mobile users from getting flooded with SMS spam.  You'll want to make sure that the system you're running this from has a public IP that resolves both forward & backward in DNS and also make sure it's not listed on any spam blacklists like [spamhaus](https://www.spamhaus.org/lookup/).

Comment: monstly you also need to authentificate yourself. can you post the "sample.txt"

Comment: @recycler - sample.txt is just a text file with let's say contains just 1 line "Hello World"

Comment: Just saw your update about Verizon vs. AT&T.  How old is the phone number for AT&T you're trying to use?  (How old is the account it's associated with?)  I've had my mobile # for years, back when it was Cingular and I'm able to send texts to my phone using 9876543210@mobile.mycingular.com.  That may only work for "grandfathered" Cingular numbers like mine though.

Comment: @BruceP - Phone number is about 3 years old and iphone 6 which I am using with AT&T network less than a year old. I am not sure if this makes any difference. I see that SMS gateway for you is different - mobile.mycingular.com.

Comment: make sure you're network route's not being blocked, `ping txt.att.net` ? (What you have works for me with other providers, so either its your network or as above, your IP is on a spam list, etc OR att as stopped this service, (I'd really be surprized if that was the case)). Hm.. just tried `ping att.net` getting Request timed out, Oh well :-( ).  Good luck.